# JSON Expansion Error in JSON

Tags: ajax, json, jquery-ajaxq

hi i need to loop this result as a options for select box this is as json format,it is the result of jquery ajax success massage please help me

console.log(result); returns

[{"id":"1","country_id":"1","state_name":"Af 1"},{"id":"2","country_id":"1","state_name":"Af 2"}]

Comment: success: function(result){
            console.log(result);

Comment: you just need to loop the values or assign them to a select?

Comment: how to loop json result

Comment: ok, is that `result` a string? what happens when you do `console.log(result[0])`? I dont understand what you want to do with the select box

Comment: Are you looking for something like - http://plnkr.co/edit/dLauEfv6TkUD24LwaJAu?p=preview